# Are enums only named integers, types or neither of both?

Tags: c#, enums

Fun with enums in C#. Take one generic list that is created to store some Enum that you had defined previously and add few items in it. Iterate with foreach or `GetEnumerator<T>()` but specify some other enum then the original and see what happens. I was expecting InvalidCastException or something like that but it perfectly works :).

For the illustration let's take a simple console application and create two enums there: Cars and Animals:

```
    public enum Cars
    {
        Honda = 0,
        Toyota = 1,
        Chevrolet = 2
    }
    public enum Animals
    {
        Dog = 0,
        Cat = 1,
        Tiger = 2
    }
```

And do this in main method:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();
        List<Animals> animals = new List<Animals>();
        cars.Add(Cars.Chevrolet);
        cars.Add(Cars.Honda);
        cars.Add(Cars.Toyota);

        foreach (Animals isItACar in cars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(isItACar.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It will print this in console:

> ```
> Tiger
> Dog
> Cat
> ```

Why is this happening? My first guess was that enum is not actually a Type by himself it's just and int but that's not true: If we write:

`Console.WriteLine(Animals.Tiger.GetType().FullName);` 
We will get his fully qualified name printed! So why this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enum types are distinct, but you're being confused by an implicit cast which is in foreach.

Let's rewrite your loop a bit:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();
    List<Animals> animals = new List<Animals>();
    cars.Add(Cars.Chevrolet);
    cars.Add(Cars.Honda);
    cars.Add(Cars.Toyota);

    foreach (Cars value in cars)
    {
        // This time the cast is explicit.
        Animals isItACar = (Animals) value;
        Console.WriteLine(isItACar.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now does the result surprise you? Hopefully not, except possibly the fact that you *can* cast from one enum to another. This is just a more explicit version of what your original code is doing.

The fact that there's a cast implicit in every `foreach` loop (even though it's usually a no-op) is the bit which most developers would find confusing, I think.

From section 8.8.4 of the C# 3.0 spec:

> The above steps, if successful,
>   unambiguously produce a collection
>   type C, enumerator type E and element
>   type T. A foreach statement of the
>   form

```
foreach (V v in x)  embedded-statement
```

> is then expanded to:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        V v;
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

The enumeration conversion itself is covered in section 6.2.2:

> The explicit enumeration conversions
>   are:

- From sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, or decimal to any enum-type.
- From any enum-type to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, or decimal.
- From any enum-type to any other enum-type.

> An explicit enumeration conversion
>   between two types is processed by
>   treating any participating enum-type
>   as the underlying type of that
>   enum-type, and then performing an
>   implicit or explicit numeric
>   conversion between the resulting
>   types. For example, given an enum-type
>   E with and underlying type of int, a
>   conversion from E to byte is processed
>   as an explicit numeric conversion
>   (§6.2.1) from int to byte, and a
>   conversion from byte to E is processed
>   as an implicit numeric conversion
>   (§6.1.2) from byte to int.

Comment: Yes very good answer. I realize now that explicit cast between enums of any type would not fail since they are practically an integers, and there was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, an Enum is a statically-typed value with a string representation and a number. When you call `ToString()` on an enum, it will return the string representation. When you call `GetType()` on an enum, you'll get the static enumeration type. If you cast an enum to `int`, you'll get the integer value for the enum.

Enums are supposed to be strongly-typed but there are some things you need to be aware of, like the fact that any integer can be cast to any enum even if it doesn't have a corresponding declaration (in which case the string representation will be the same as the number's).

In the CLR, enums (like `bool`s) are just treated as `int`s but if you called GetType() or GetString() it calls the versions that do what was described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also derive an enum from a specific type.

```
public enum Cats : byte { ... }
public enum Dogs : int { ... }
```